# All .cc files getting rebuilt after a change in just one of them

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tdd, googletest

Each class in my application has a .h and .cc file. However in my unit-test project things are a little different. Here I have a gtest unit test class for each application class I wish to test and each class is defined and declared in a **.cc** file only. So no .h.

I made this decision because I didn't feel I needed .h files:

- I wont be reusing a test class elsewhere and because it is a pain, and
- when doing tdd to jump around all the time between testx.h, testx.cc, x.cc, x.h, ix.h, mockz.h etc, etc.

  - So one less file I thought.

I get .obj files for each test .cc file, however in VS2012 at least, a change in one such file results in all other test .cc files being rebuilt.

Please note that the class under test are not being rebuilt in this case, just these "funny" .cc files where I have my tests. Such a file looks like this:

TestX.cc:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "X.h"
#include "factory/YFactory.h"

namespace A
{

class TestX : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    TestX() {
    }
};

TEST_F (TestX, firstTest)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
}
```

Am I wrong in your opinion to implement my tests like this? If not, why are they being rebuilt all the time?

To work around this problem at the moment I am only including the test .cc file for the class I am implementing. All other files remain in the project.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you have organized your code. First thing I would test is whether the files get rebuilt even if you have made no changes. In general I would avoid .cc files with Visual Studio, it's happier with .cpp I think.